# How do i add media files/folder to a winform app .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, software-distribution

I am making an example app of a game. I have a folder i set as the current directory from within visual studios which includes pngs,ogg,config.json,etc.

When i 'publish' these files are not included. How do i properly add a media files/folders into the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You right click on the files you need, select `Properties` and set the `Copy To Output Directory` setting to either `Copy Always` or `Copy if Newer`.

This will make sure they are "published".

Comment: cool. Is there a way to add a folder instead of dozens and dozens of files?

Comment: hmm, i  can add an ./resource folder and change my directory in main(). this solution looks fine.

Comment: i also set built action to content

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, select all files you wish to be published (could be all files in a folder) using shift-click. Then right-click the list of selected files and choose *properties*. Set the *Build Action* to 'Content' and *Copy to Output Directory* to 'Copy always' (or 'Copy if newer')

Comment: i also set built action to content

Comment: The key for me was setting Build Action to 'Content'